# C++ is it possible to output all data inside an array without knowing how long the array is?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to output all data in an array without knowing how many members it has.

Is there perhaps any built in function or libraries that show how many members are there in an array?

Comment: Are you talking about built-in arrays or standard containers such as `std::vector` or `std::array`?

Comment: Does the array have a marker to mark the last element in it? (see C style strings)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `std::vector` built-in class
just use `#include <vector>` to use it

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int xs[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::for_each(std::begin(xs), std::end(xs), [](int const& x) { std::cout << x << std::endl;});
}
```

Notice however that the size of the array is still a known information (more precisely, a compile-time information). In the above, we simply avoid handling explicitly that information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - and no. If you have an actual array, i.e. `int a[N];` then the answer is very obvious: you array has N elements. If you have only a pointer (`int* a`), probably due to the array-to-pointer decay, then the answer is no.

If you want to have a function that determines the size of an array, try this function template:

```
template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arr_length(T const (&)[N]) {
  return N;
}

int  main() {
  int iarr[] = {42, 43, 44};
  constexpr auto length = arr_length(iarr);

  double darr[length] = {};
}
```

For arrays passed to some function as pointers, there are only few possibilities to determine the length:

- by explicitly passing the size of the array as second parameter
- by passing a second pointer to one past the end of the array, the size is then simply the difference of the two pointers
- by having a sentry element in the array that denotes the end. The most popular example is the `'\0'` delimiter in C-style strings (i.e. character arrays)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. 
I'd suggest you to use a `std::vector`, it would solve your problems.

In case it is a `std::array` you can use a `for_each` or a

```
for(const auto item : arr)
```

if your array contains pointers, and you default initialized them to `nullptr`, you can check if the pointer is valid and print only if it's not `nullptr`.

```
    std::array<object*, 10> arr = {};
    for(const auto item : arr){
      if(item!=nullptr)
         //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you looking for this : 
`int arraySize = (sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray));`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  int myArray[] = {0,0,0,0,0};
  int arraySize = (sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(*myArray));
  cout<<arraySize<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Output is

> 5

for my program

[image]

Comment: This is dangerous. When you pass the array in a function it suddenly stops working. I prefer the template version that fails to compile when this happens. Also the parenthesis near the `sizeof`'s are unnecessary.

Comment: also the type returned by `sizeof` is `std::size_t` not `int`